# Trigger inserting date as 30/05/9305 22:58

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers, oracle12c

In my application, I have a trigger defined to do insertion for a table and a view, all the entries inserted are perfect, except for the date parameter, which gets inserted as `'30/05/9305 22:58'`. The values that the trigger gets is through the UI, I have checked the entire workflow from the java code from getting the values from the UI to passing it to the trigger, everything looks perfect.
Can anyone help me identify what is going wrong and where?

> Date selected was 07/02/2018 which got transformed to 30/05/9305 22:58

Here is a short snap of the trigger that is being used for this:

```
create or replace trigger "TEST_TRIGGER"
instead of insert on "MY_VIEW"
referencing NEW as n
for each row
 BEGIN
 insert into DEMO_TABLE
     (id, emp_name,report_date,insert_date) 
     select 
     demo.table_seq.nextval,:n.id,:n.emp_name,:n.report_date,sysdate from dual;
END;
```

Comment: How is `report_date` defined? (assuming the issue is with `report_date`.) Is it a `date` column?

Comment: `select ... from dual` is not needed, make simple `insert into DEMO_TABLE
     (id, emp_name,report_date,insert_date) values (demo.table_seq.nextval,:n.emp_name,:n.report_date,sysdate)`

Comment: @WilliamRobertson it is defined as TIMESTAMP...

Comment: Please show us your insert SQL statement (include values).

Comment: Hi... When I switched to using Oracle Database 12c EE it worked without a problem, the above issue occurred when I was using Oracle Database 11g. But this switching isn't feasible, so trying to find the underlying cause. If anyone is aware of it please let me know... Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement could be wrong. it has extra column in the select

```
insert into DEMO_TABLE
     (id, emp_name,report_date,insert_date) 
     select 
     :n.id,:n.emp_name,:n.report_date,sysdate from dual;
```